# IntersectionObserver: starting and ending the observer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to trigger the `IntersectionObserver` when the top of the element hits the top of the window and when the bottom of the element hits the bottom of the window.

The element I'm observing has a height of `200vh`.

With the following code I'm able to trigger the `IntersectionObserver` when the element reaches the top of the page:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  // trigger observer
}, {
  rootMargin: '0px 0px -100% 0px',
});

observer.observe(ref.current);
```

This works because the `bottom` of the `rootMargin` has a `-100%` value.

But when I add `100%` to the `top` of the `rootMargin` it won't work.

Please checkout in full window:
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-bose-v3on2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-bose-v3on2?file=/src/App.js